# Call viewstack (main app) from component

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a viewstack in my main application

```
public var currentStep:int;

<mx:ViewStack id="step" selectedIndex="{currentStep}">
     <comp:Choosecar id="choosecar" />
     <comp:Configcar id="configcar" />
</mx>
```

I'm using a drag and drop inside to choosecar component, so I want to change the 'currentstep' - which is a variable of the main application - with +1 so the viewstack changes to the second component 'configcar'. The only solution I found is calling a component from the main application, I need it the other way around but I can't find it.

Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks!

Comment: Why? just WHY is everyone hell bent on calling parent functions from a child? It would be better to throw an event in the child and listen for it in the parent

Answer (score 3):

In your component Choosecar, you may dispatch an event, let's say "switchToConfig". I assumed you meant dropdown instead of "drag and drop".

```
<mx:ComboBox change="dispatcheEvent(new Event('switchToConfig'))" />
```

At the beginning of your component's MXML you have to declare the dispatched event:

```
[Event(name="switchToConfig", type="flash.events.Event")]
```

Now you will be able to catch the event in the top application

```
[Bindable] public var currentStep:int;

<mx:ViewStack id="step" selectedIndex="{currentStep}">
   <comp:Choosecar id="choosecar" switchToConfig="currentStep = 1" />
   <comp:Configcar id="configcar" />
</mx>
```

Cheers